# How can I make android homescreen shortcut for my website?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a way to make an android app without installation. I mean the website feature "Add to homescreen". Is there any way I can do this with javascript ?

Comment: Do you mean a [Progressive Web App](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/)?

Comment: That is not possible. You cant make android to create a shortcut from a web site

Comment: @TmTron I have no knowledge about that yet.

Comment: @ilkerkaran what about the website that has "Add to homescreen" the already have an app installed ?

Comment: For that your website (Now called a Progressive Web App) needs to have at least a manifest.json file and a service worker able to handle fetch requests. For more information see https://web.dev/install-criteria

Comment: @RohanShah ok tnx

Comment: gonna have to read your suggestions guys. tnx

Comment: Could you find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am Currently using framework7 and using this pro7: https://github.com/NowDB/Pro7

and it using Web App Manifest to archive "Add to homescreen" function.

Maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: tnx for this help.